# Kafka - Setting high linger.ms and batch.size not helping

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to improve Kafka producer throughput, we have CSV reports which are getting process and publish to Kafka topic. using default Kafka settings we are getting on avg `300-500 kbps` Kafka throughput. to improve the throughput I have tried testing some combinations with `linger.ms` and `batch.size` but it's not helping.

tried with

```
"linger.ms= 30000","batch.size= 1000000","buffer.memory=16777216"
"linger.ms= 40000","batch.size= 1500000","buffer.memory=16777216"
```

even tried with lesser linger.ms and batch.size
`linger.ms = 200, batch.size=65000`

but still, throughput is around 150-200 kbps

but throughput is just decreasing to 100-150kbps.

Kafka topic has 12 partitions.

```
ack is all, and compression is snappy
```

any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

There is a comprehensive [white paper](https://www.confluent.io/blog/optimizing-apache-kafka-deployment/) from Confluent which explains how to increase throughput and which configurations to look at.

Basically, you have already done the right steps by increasing `batch.size` and tuning `linger.ms`. Depending on your requirements of potential data loss you may also reduce the `retries`. As an important factor for increasing throughput, you should use a `compression.type` in your producer while at the same time set the `compression.type=producer` at broker-level.

Remember that Kafka scales with the partitions and this can only happen if you have enough brokers in your cluster. Having many partitions, all located on the same broker will not increase throughput.

To summarize, the white paper mentiones the following producer configurations to increase throughput:

```
batch.size: increase to 100000 - 200000 (default 16384)
linger.ms: increase to 10 - 100 (default 0)
compression.type=lz4 (default none)
acks=1 (default 1)
retries=0 (default 0)
buffer.memory: increase if there are a lot of partitions (default 33554432)
```

Keep in mind, that in the end, each cluster behaves differently. In addition, each use case has different structure of messages (volume, frequency, byte size, ...). Therefore, it is important to get an understanding of the mentioned producer configurations and test their sensitivity on your actual cluster.

Comment: `ack is all, and compression is snappy`

I have also edited my question and added this info

Comment: Gzip has a better compression ratio like 30% than snappy and it will help you in throughput as it significantly reduces the size of the batch.